# pyspark udf for mutils columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe as

```
import pandas as pd

ndf = pd.DataFrame({'a':[False, False,True,True,False], 'b':[False, False,False,False, True]})

ndf_s = sqlContext.createDataFrame(ndf)
```

I would like to get a new column named as "action". This could contain two values, if the ndf['a'] is True the "action" has value as "I am a", if ndf['b'] is True the "action" has value as "I am b". Otherwise get value None. In case both column are true, then return value as "I am a and b".In other word I would like to get a DataFrame as:

```
ndf_result = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a':[False, False,True,True,False], 'b':[False, False,False,False, True], 'action':[None, None, 'I am a', 'I am a', 'I am b']}))
```

Comment: Is there any chance both columns are True?

Comment: possible, in that case, send the "action" to "I am a and b"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `when.otherwise`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

ndf_s.withColumn("action", F.when(
        ndf_s["a"] & ndf_s["b"], "I am a and b"
    ).otherwise(
        F.when(
            ndf_s["a"], "I am a"
        ).otherwise(
            F.when(ndf_s["b"], "I am b")
        )
    )
).show()
+-----+-----+------------+
|    a|    b|      action|
+-----+-----+------------+
| true| true|I am a and b|
|false|false|        null| 
| true|false|      I am a|
| true|false|      I am a|
|false| true|      I am b|
+-----+-----+------------+
```

---

Another option with `udf`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.udf
def action(col_a, col_b):
    if col_a and col_b:
        return "I am a and b"
    elif col_a:
        return "I am a"
    elif col_b:
        return "I am b"

ndf_s.withColumn("action", action(ndf_s["a"], ndf_s["b"])).show()
+-----+-----+------------+  
|    a|    b|      action|
+-----+-----+------------+
| true| true|I am a and b|
|false|false|        null|
| true|false|      I am a|
| true|false|      I am a|
|false| true|      I am b|
+-----+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Psidom, thank you for your nice solution! Is there are any change to use "udf" to achieve this result?

Comment: You can use `udf` for this if the condition is complicated, updated an option with `udf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as udf
import pandas as pd

ndf = pd.DataFrame({'a':[False, False,True,True,False], 'b':[False, False,False,False, True]})

ndf_s = sqlContext.createDataFrame(ndf)


def get_expected_string(a,b):
    if a and b:
       return "I am a and b"
    elif a:
       return "I am a"
    elif b:
       return "I am b"
    else: return None

# defining udf function for get_expected_string
get_expected_string_udf = udf(get_expected_string, StringType())

ndf_s = ndf_s.withColumn("action",get_expected_string_udf("a","b"))

ndf_s.show()
+-----+-----+------------+  
|    a|    b|      action|
+-----+-----+------------+
| true| true|I am a and b|
|false|false|        null|
| true|false|      I am a|
| true|false|      I am a|
|false| true|      I am b|
+-----+-----+------------+
```